# Regex with < and >

Tags: c#, regex

ok i have a file that may or may not be newlined or carriage fed. frankly i need to ignore that. I need to search the document find all the < and matching > tags and remove everything inside them. I've been trying to get this to work for a bit my current regex is:

```
private Regex BracketBlockRegex = new Regex("<.*>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
....
resultstring = BracketBlockRegex.Replace(filecontents, "");
```

but this doesn't seem to be working because it catches WAY to much. any clues? is there something wierd with the < and > symbols in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a non-greedy variant of your regex:

```
<[^>]*>
```

What you have, `<.*>`, will match the first `<` followed by everything up to the *last* `>`, whereas what you want is to match to the *first* one.

Answer (score 7):

Replace

```
<.*>
```

with

```
<.*?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are greedy and you've got a period which equates to ANYTHING which just so happens to include the greater than and less than characters.

Try this...

```
<[^<>]*>
```

[Arguably the best Regular Expression resource on the Internet.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: nope. this doesn't work. have to remember i do need to consider the newline characters and line feeds as possibly inclusive to the match.

Comment: @Arthur: It is inclusive of carriage returns and line feeds.  Did you mean exclusive?  If that's the case then you'd want <[^<>\r\n]*>

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
private Regex BracketBlockRegex = new Regex("<.*?>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note you may need to add some parsing qualifiers about how to interrupt the source data.

An HTML tag can be split up at white space onto different lines.

<IMG
SRC="blah.jpg"
ALT="blah"
>

Some regular expression parsers may, or may not, match **.** to \r or \n depending on settings.